# Grails : Generate text file for GSP

Tags: grails

I am working with a Grails 2.3.6 application.

I tried many different things to generate PDF, but most of them failed.

Is it possible to generate a text file of the contents of GSP file? Then have a button called EXPORT and when user clicks on that, the text file will download into there system.

Will it be possible to do that by passing the URL of GSP file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite straightforward. You just need to specify the response type (text/plain) in the render method from your controller. You can have plain text in the gsp file and use the tags where needed.

```
def textFile = {
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="textFile.txt"')

    render view: 'textFile', contentType: 'text/plain'
}
```

textFile.gsp:

> Dear ${name},
>   This is a text file.

As for pdf, I recommend the amazingly good [grails rendering plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rendering).

Comment: Your code render the GSP with full HTML source. That's not what am looking for. I am looking for just the data in the HTML/GSP page to be saved into a text (.txt) file. I don't need the HTML tags or CSS styles in the text file. Only the data is needed.

Comment: There is no html source in my gsp file and I didn't specify a layout. If you need the text file downloaded instead of rendered in the browser, set the Content-Disposition header. Will edit the answer to add...

Comment: Unfortunately it does the same in text file too. It downloads a text file, but that file contains all the HTML & CSS elements plus the DATA. I just want the data. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: My function look like this:
def textFile () {
  String uNumber = params.userInstance;
  String info = params.userInfoText
  userOrder uObj = userOrder.findByNumber(uNumber);
  response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="textFile.txt"')
  render view: 'updateIndex', model: [userOrderInstanceList : uObj], contentType: 'text/plain'
 }

Comment: Please UPDATED section above

Comment: You obviously didn't read my answer. My view is 'textFile'. My textFile.gsp contains no html. Your updateIndex contains html, so of course that is what it renders.

Comment: So is there a way of generating text file with only DATA for a GSP containing HTML/CSS tags?